# Given commutative non-linear vector fields, the linearization commute

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems, lie-algebras

Given $f_1, f_2$ be $C^1$-vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we define the lie bracket

$$ [f_1,f_2](x)=\frac{df_2}{dx}(x)f_1(x)-\frac{df_1}{dx}(x)f_2(x)$$

They are said to commute if the lie bracket is identically $0$.

We need to show that if $f_1, f_2\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are commuting and $f_1(0)=f_2(0)=0$, then the Jacobian matrices $Df_1(0)$ and $Df_2(0)$ commute. I have no idea where to begin. A hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $d_xf_2(f_1(x)) - d_xf_1(f_2(x))$ ?

Comment: @Max The book gives the above definition. But your definition actually would be consistent with the usual commutator of matrices i.e. if $f_i(x)=A_ix$ as it is with this definition. In the case of your definition is the claim easy to see?